Lost a registered Kansai-area ICOCA card, how do I recover its value in Tokyo?
I'm currently in Tokyo, and managed to lose a registered ICOCA card that has a couple of thousand yen on it.  Is there any way I can recover or transfer its value in Tokyo without going back to Osaka/Kansai?

As far as I can tell, the only way to reissue an ICOCA card is to physically go to a station counter within the ICOCA service area,  full stop.  You're also charged ¥1050 for the privilege (service fee plus new card deposit).
If you have a SMART ICOCA/credit card combo, it's a different story, but these aren't an option for visitors to Japan anyway.
